# How to remove this white line on the right?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

Watch this screenshot carefully. There is a white line on the right like there is a white border on the right side. I don't want it. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

```
setContent {
    TestingAndroidApp2Theme {
        Scaffold {
                contentPadding ->
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(contentPadding)
            ) {
                val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState()
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                ModalBottomSheet(
                    sheetState = sheetState,
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        scope.launch {
                            sheetState.hide()
                        }
                    },
                    scrimColor = Color.Black,
                    containerColor = Color.DarkGray,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(16.dp)
                        .border(1.dp, Color.Red)
                ) {
                    // Your main screen content here

                    Button(onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            sheetState.show()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text("Show Bottom Sheet")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```